# PHP include external file and make an Array

Tags: php, arrays, include

I want to include an external file, and then get all the content, remove the only HTML on the page `<br />` and replace with `,` and fire it into an array.

**datafeed.php**

```
john_23<br />
john_5<br />
john_23<br />
john_5<br />
```

**grabber.php**

```
<?php
// grab the url
include("http://site.com/datafeed.php");

//$lines = file('http://site.com/datafeed.php);

// loop through array, show HTML source as HTML source.
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {

    // replace the <br /> with a ,
    $removeBreak = str_replace("<br />",",", $removeBreak);
    $removeBreak = htmlspecialchars($line);
    // echo $removeBreak;
}

// fill our array into string called SaleList
$SaleList = ->array("");
```

I want to load a php file from the server directory, get the HTML contents of this file and place it into a useable array.

It would look like

```
$SaleList = -getAndCreateArray from the file above >array("");
$SaleList = ->array("john_23, john_5, john_23");
```

Comment: `include()` on remote urls is dangerous. You're giving an external server COMPLETE control of your script, and therefore complete control of your website.  Beyond that... is there a question there? You don't mention having a problem, so if this code is working fine, then why post it?

Comment: include is the only file operator you know? what about file(), file_get_contents()?

Comment: @MarcB this code doesn't work though.

Comment: @Marc B: A cursory look at the code he posted indicates that it's not working fine. His question can be summed up as "My code doesn't work. How can I changed it to make it work?"

Comment: @Asaph: yes, and perhaps the OP should actually say what the problem is. I can see that he's using `$removeBreak` without ever defining it, but without know what the OP actually wants this code to do, that could just be a bit of dead code.

Comment: @Marc B: The first sentence of the question clearly states what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Clearly the OP wants an answer. His code is not working

Comment: Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Bad arguments. in /home/www/gorgeouscouture/srx2.php on line 18

Comment: $string = implode(',', $varq);

Comment: Same here. You asks a question that makes no sense and instead of making it clear you only smiles.

Comment: lol, let me phrase it again, edited.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid: your code sample doesn't have an implode(). The error means you're not passing it an array, so $varq is probably a string or other non-array type variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version of `grabber.php`:

```
<?php
function getSaleList($file) {
    $saleList = array();
    $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
    if (!$handle) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Unable to open ' . $file);
    }
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $matches = array();
        if (preg_match('/^(.*?)(\s*\<br\s*\/?\>\s*)?$/i', $line, $matches)) {
            $line = $matches[1];
        }
        array_push($saleList, htmlspecialchars($line));
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        throw new RuntimeException('unexpected fgets() fail on file ' . $file);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    return $saleList;
}

$saleList = getSaleList('datafeed.php');

print_r($saleList);
?>
```

By using a regular expression to find the `<br />`, the code is able to deal with many variations such as `<br>`, `<BR>`, `<BR />`, `<br/>`, etc.

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => john_23
    [1] => john_5
    [2] => john_23
    [3] => john_5
)
```

Comment: if($function=="query" && in_array($someID, $saleList)){
 //
}

Comment: I hate that type of output. I just want it the output I showed above.

Comment: I want to do my if statement above.

Comment: If you don't like that output, simply remove the line `print_r($saleList);` which is only there to prove that the code does what it's supposed to do. The `$saleList` variable already contains the array you're looking for.

Comment: It's not clear to me how `$function=="query"` fits in, but assuming that that part of your code is working, you should be able to use the `$saleList` array from my answer and plug it in there.

Comment: I get an error. Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in /home/www/cartapp.php on line 1592

Comment: if ($promocode=="nov11" && in_array($newitemID, $SaleList)) {
 $promocode_validate_check = $_POST['promocode'];
}

Comment: Assuming that error occurs on the line `if($function=="query" && in_array($someID, $saleList)){`, it would indicate that the `$saleList` variable is either undefined or not an array. Perhaps it's not in scope or not yet initialized when you make that call?

Comment: echo $saleList; returns Array. Only Print_r returns your output.

Comment: The output is not important. The point is that your file has been parsed and your array has been created. Do you have what you need?

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have grasped what include does.

If you want to process the contents of some file using your PHP code, then include is the wrong construct - you should be using file() or file_get_contents().

i.e. using the line of code you've commented out in your question.

Where include is the right construct to use....you should never, ever include remote files directly - its much *MUCH* slower than a local filesystem read - and very insecure. There are times when it does make sense to fetch the file from a remote location and cache it locally though.

And you should NEVER have inline HTML nor PHP code (html in PHP variables/conditional expressions, and PHP defines/class/function/include/require are OK) in an include file.

Answer (score 0):

May you need something like this?

```
$file = file_get_contents('newfile.php');
echo str_replace("<br>", ",", $file);
```

But I didn't get what you try to insert into the array...

Comment: This code works fine, however it prints ALL the PHP, it does not do the HTML.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid for the external file it will return HTML.

Comment: But how do I grab it into an array.